# Pipeline List with Constant Parameters

Tags: f#, pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline that consists of the main parameter being a list with a constant.

As a simple example

```
type ClockType = | In | Out
let ClockMap index offset = 
    match index with
    | index when index + offset % 2 = 0 -> In
    | _ -> Out
 let MapIt offset = [0 .. 23] |> List.map offset
```

It works when I take out the `offset`. I've tried doing a `tuple` but then it doesn't like the `int list`. What is the best way to go about this?

I'm just learning F# so bear with me.

Comment: Is `index with index` supposed to be `index when index`?

Comment: @ildjarn, Yes, I'll fix that.

Comment: I think you want to swap the order of the parameters

Comment: swapping index and offset gives me a "Type mismatch." Error.

Comment: I meant swapping them everywhere 0 in both use and declaration

Comment: `let MapIt offset = [0 .. 23] |> List.map offset` for this line to be coherent `offset` would need to be a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
type ClockType = In | Out
let clockMap offset index = if (index + offset) % 2 = 0 then In else Out
let mapIt offset = [0 .. 23] |> List.map (clockMap offset)
```

Output would be:

```
mapIt 3 |> printfn "%A"
// [Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In; Out;
//  In; Out; In; Out; In; Out; In]
```

If so, there were multiple issues:

- `clockMap`'s parameters were backwards
- `%` has higher precedence than `+`
- `clockMap` was never being called (and `offset` needs to be partially applied to `clockMap`)

The change from `match` to `if` was purely for readability, and idiomatically, non-literal `let` bound values start with lowercase characters (type names and class properties/methods start with uppercase).